# Where is /dev/dsp or /dev/audio?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have to apply `sudo chmod a+r /dev/dsp` or `/dev/audio` but in my Ubuntu 12.10 i do not have such. Where is then the PCM  sound file for ssh?

```
chmod: cannot access `/dev/dsp': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `/dev/audio': No such file or directory
```

Follow up:

https://superuser.com/questions/244173/missing-dev-dsp-under-ubuntu

I want to stream the sound output and input. So that i can capture any audio in/out to a file for recording.

Comment: `/dev/dsp` and `/dev/audio` (along with `/dev/mixer`) haven't been present in Ubuntu since 9.04. This is because they now use PulseAudio to manage the sound system. You're going to need to add a little context as to *why* you need them before we can help :)

Comment: @jackweirdy: i want to stream the sound output and input. So that i can capture any audio in/out to a file for recording.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to install pulseaudio's volume control and then use that to reroute the program you are recording with to the program you are trying to record.

(I will add screenshots a little later).

Comment: Hello, when you'll add screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who lands here in the 2020s while trying to get some ancient program working that still only speaks OSS, you want [OSS Proxy Daemon](https://sourceforge.net/projects/osspd/), which should be in your distro repos as `osspd` or something similar.

It will use the kernel's CUSE (Character Devices in Userspace) API to create OSS devices (eg. `/dev/dsp`) that feed into PulseAudio or Pipewire.

Comment: Tested in 2024 and confirmed to work well with ubuntu 23.10.